# Performance with matrix class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, loops, dynamic

I was performance profiling our library and noticed that most time is spent in matrix manipulations.
I wanted to see whether I could improve performance by changing the order of the matrix loops or by changing the matrix class definition from row major to column major.
Questions:

1. Below I test 2 cases. Test case 1 is always the fastest, no matter whether my matrix is row or columns major. Why is that?
2. Turning on vectorization improves Test case 1 with a factor 2, why is that?

Performance profiling is done with Very Sleepy.
I used Visual Studio 2019 – platformtoolset v142, and compiled in 32-bit.

Our library defines a matrix template where the underlying is a dynamic array where the ordering is column major (full code follows below):

```
Type& operator()(int row, int col)
{
   return pArr[row + col * m_rows];
}

Type operator()(int row, int col) const
{
   return pArr[row + col * m_rows];
}
```

We also have a matrix class specific for doubles:

```
class DMatrix : public TMatrix<double>
{
public:
    // Constructors:
    DMatrix() : TMatrix<double>() { }
    DMatrix(int rows, int cols) : TMatrix<double>(rows, cols, true) {}

};
```

I ran 2 test cases that perform nested loop operations on randomly filled matrices. The difference between Test case 1 and 2 is the order of the inner loops.

```
       int nrep = 10000; // Large number of calculations
       int nstate = 400;
       int nstep = 400;
       int nsec = 3; // 100 times smaller than nstate and nstep
       DMatrix value(nstate, nsec);
       DMatrix Rc(nstate, 3 * nstep);
       DMatrix rhs(nstate, nsec);

    // Test case 1
    for (int k = 0; k < nrep; k++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < nstep; n++) {
            int diag = 3 * n + 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < nstate; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nsec; j++) { 
                    value(i, j) = (rhs(i, j) - Rc(i, diag - 1) * value(i - 1, j)) / Rc(i, diag);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Test case 2
    for (int k = 0; k < nrep; k++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < nstep; n++) {
            int diag = 3 * n + 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < nsec; j++) {
                for (int i = 1; i < nstate; i++) {
                    value(i, j) = (rhs(i, j) - Rc(i, diag - 1) * value(i - 1, j)) / Rc(i, diag);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Since the matrix is column major, I expected that I would get the best performance when the inner loop follows a column, due to nearby elements being CPU cached, but instead it is doing the opposite. Note that nstep and nstate are typically 100 times larger than nsec.

[image: Performance column major matrix]

When I turn on vectorization:
“Advanced Vector Extensions 2” in Code Generation/Enable Enhanced Instruction Set, the performance difference gets even larger:

[image: Performance column major matrix with vector optimizations]

When I turn off the vectorization and make the matrix row major:

```
    Type& operator()(int row, int col)
    {
        return pArr[col + row*m_cols];
    }

    Type operator()(int row, int col) const
    {
        return pArr[col + row*m_cols];
    }
```

I don’t get any difference in performance compared to when the matrix was column major:
[image: Performance row major matrix]

With vector optimizations:

[image: Performance row major matrix with vector optimizations]

The full code. matrix.h:

```
#ifndef __MATRIX_H
#define __MATRIX_H

#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

template<class Type>
class TMatrix
{
public:
    TMatrix();                                                                                         // Default constructor
    TMatrix(int rows, int cols, bool init = false);                            // Constructor with dimensions  + flag to default initialize or not
    TMatrix(const TMatrix& mat);                                  // Copy constructor
    TMatrix& operator=(const TMatrix& mat); // Assignment operator
    ~TMatrix();                             // Destructor   

    // Move constructor/assignment
    TMatrix(TMatrix&& mat) noexcept;
    TMatrix& operator=(TMatrix&& mat) noexcept;

    // Get matrix dimensions
    int no_rows() const { return m_rows; }
    int no_columns() const { return m_cols; }


    Type& operator()(int row, int col)
    {
        assert(row >= 0 && row < m_rows&& col >= 0 && col < m_cols);
        return pArr[row + col * m_rows];   // elements in a column lay next to each other
        //return pArr[col + row*m_cols];  // elements in a row lay next to each other
    }

    Type operator()(int row, int col) const
    {
        assert(row >= 0 && row < m_rows&& col >= 0 && col < m_cols);
        return pArr[row + col * m_rows];
        // return pArr[col + row*m_cols];
    }

protected:
    void clear();

    Type* pArr;
    int m_rows, m_cols;
};

//**************************************************************
// Implementation of TMatrix
//**************************************************************

// Default constructor
template<class Type>
TMatrix<Type>::TMatrix()
{
    m_rows = 0;
    m_cols = 0;
    pArr = 0;
}

// Constructor with matrix dimensions (rows, cols)
template<class Type>
TMatrix<Type>::TMatrix(int rows, int cols, bool init)
{
    pArr = 0;
    m_rows = rows;
    m_cols = cols;

    if (m_rows > 0 && m_cols > 0)
        if (init)
            pArr = new Type[m_rows * m_cols]();
        else
            pArr = new Type[m_rows * m_cols];                   // TODO: check for p = NULL (memory allocation error, which will triger a GPF)
    else
    {
        m_rows = 0;
        m_cols = 0;
    }
}

// Copy constructor
template<class Type>
TMatrix<Type>::TMatrix(const TMatrix& mat)
{
    pArr = 0;
    m_rows = mat.m_rows;
    m_cols = mat.m_cols;

    if (m_rows > 0 && m_cols > 0)
    {
        int dim = m_rows * m_cols;
        pArr = new Type[dim];

        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            pArr[i] = mat.pArr[i];
    }
    else
    {
        m_rows = m_cols = 0;
    }
}

// Move constructors
template<class Type>
TMatrix<Type>::TMatrix(TMatrix&& mat) noexcept
{
    m_rows = mat.m_rows;
    m_cols = mat.m_cols;

    if (m_rows > 0 && m_cols > 0)
    {
        pArr = mat.pArr;
    }
    else
    {
        m_rows = m_cols = 0;
        pArr = 0;
    }

    mat.pArr = 0;
}

// Clear the matrix
template<class Type>
void TMatrix<Type>::clear()
{

    delete[] pArr;
    pArr = 0;
    m_rows = m_cols = 0;
}

// Destructor
template<class Type>
TMatrix<Type>::~TMatrix()
{
    clear();
}

// Move assignment
template<class Type>
TMatrix<Type>& TMatrix<Type>::operator=(TMatrix&& mat) noexcept
{

    if (this != &mat) // Check for self assignment
    {
        clear();
        m_rows = mat.m_rows;
        m_cols = mat.m_cols;

        if (m_rows > 0 && m_cols > 0)
        {
            pArr = mat.pArr;
        }
        else
        {
            m_rows = m_cols = 0;
        }
        mat.pArr = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

// Assignment operator with check for self-assignment
template<class Type>
TMatrix<Type>& TMatrix<Type>::operator=(const TMatrix& mat)
{
    if (this != &mat)        // Guard against self assignment
    {
        clear();
        m_rows = mat.m_rows;
        m_cols = mat.m_cols;

        if (m_rows > 0 && m_cols > 0)
        {
            int dim = m_rows * m_cols;
            pArr = new Type[dim];

            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
                pArr[i] = mat.pArr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            m_rows = m_cols = 0;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

#endif
```

dmatrix.h:

```
#ifndef __DMATRIX_H
#define __DMATRIX_H

#include "matrix.h"
class DMatrix : public TMatrix<double>
{
public:
    // Constructors:
    DMatrix() : TMatrix<double>() { }
    DMatrix(int rows, int cols) : TMatrix<double>(rows, cols, true) {}
};
#endif
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dmatrix.h"

int main()
{
    int nrep = 10000; // Large number of calculations

    int nstate = 400;
    int nstep = 400;
    int nsec = 3; // 100 times smaller than nstate and nstep
    DMatrix value(nstate, nsec);
    DMatrix Rc(nstate, 3 * nstep);
    DMatrix rhs(nstate, nsec);

    // Give some random input
    for (int i = 0; i < Rc.no_rows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Rc.no_columns(); j++) {
            Rc(i, j) = double(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < value.no_rows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < value.no_columns(); j++) {
            value(i, j) = 1 + double(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.no_rows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rhs.no_columns(); j++) {
            rhs(i, j) = 1 + double(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }

    // Test case 1
    for (int k = 0; k < nrep; k++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < nstep; n++) {
            int diag = 3 * n + 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < nstate; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nsec; j++) { // Expectation: this is fast - inner loop follows row
                    value(i, j) = (rhs(i, j) - Rc(i, diag - 1) * value(i - 1, j)) / Rc(i, diag);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Test case 2
    for (int k = 0; k < nrep; k++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < nstep; n++) {
            int diag = 3 * n + 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < nsec; j++) {
                for (int i = 1; i < nstate; i++) { // Expectation: this is slow - inner loop walks down column
                    value(i, j) = (rhs(i, j) - Rc(i, diag - 1) * value(i - 1, j)) / Rc(i, diag);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Best regards,
Nele

Comment: `#define __DMATRIX_H` This identifier is reserved to the language implementation. By defning it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Comment: `Rc` is the largest matrix, and the indices with which you access it are independent of `j`. If the inner loop is on `j` you can use the value of `Rc(i, diag - 1)` in all `nsec` iterations.

Comment: @BennyK misread then. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in a comment, after some testing:

`Rc` is the largest matrix here (by roughly a factor of 100), and it is reasonable to assume that most of the running time is spent on handling it. When the inner loop is on `j`, you get significant improvement because `Rc(i, diag - 1)` and `Rc(i, diag)` can be reused in all iterations of the inner loop.

To make sure that this is the case, I changed the loops to the following:

```
// Test case 1
for (int k = 0; k < nrep; k++) {
    for (int i = 1; i < nstate; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nsec; j++) { // Expectation: this is fast - inner loop follows row
            value(i, j) = (rhs(i, j) -  value(i - 1, j));
        }
    }
}

// Test case 2
for (int k = 0; k < nrep; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nsec; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < nstate; i++) { // Expectation: this is slow - inner loop walks down column
            value(i, j) = (rhs(i, j) - value(i - 1, j)) ;
        }
    }
}
```

With this calculation (and different matrix sizes - 2000 by 2000, for 200 repetitions), one test case runs 10 times faster than the other (no fancy profiling, but linux's `time` gives 18s vs. ~2s).

When I change row-major and column-major the trend is reversed.

EDIT:

Conclusion - you need to select row-major/column-major based on what workes best for `Rc`, and always use *Test case 1* (if this represents the problems you're actually trying to solve).

---

Regarding vectorization - I'm not sure how this works. Maybe someone else can offer an explanation.

Comment: Hi Benny, thanks for looking into this. I also ran the performance on the original test cases but with nsec and nstate of the same order: 

int nrep = 1000; int nstate = 200; int nstep = 400; int nsec = 200; 

Column major, no optimizations: case 1: 114s, case 2: 168s.

Row major, no optimizations: case 1: 114s, case 2: 169s.

Column major, with optimizations: case 1: 37s, case 2: 145s.
Row major, with optimizations: case 1: 27s, case 2: 153s. 
I believe that these results are to be expected, assuming that Rc(i, diag -1) and Rc(i, diag) are the main drivers.

Comment: @Nele I'm not sure what you're trying to say. See edit to my answer, which might clarify things.

Comment: I understand that test case 1 is always going to be the fastest. Thanks for pointing out. With this, I am still expecting that case 1 (unmodified) performs better for a column major matrix, but it turns out that performance is the same.

Comment: @Nele I guess that the numbers are small enough for the `rhs` and `value` matrices to fit into the cache (or something near enough to it). Even with your original example I begin to see a difference of 40-50% in case 1, between row-major and column-major, when I increase `nsec` to 400.

Comment: I can confirm that.Thanks for the help.